# SAS Standard Macros

Tags: sas, sas-macro

The following variables seem to be a standard macro in multiple SAS Code that I come across. Can someone explain the following please?

```
&dsin.
&dsout.
&cj_yyyymm_1.
&cj_yyyymm_2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are not "standard" macro variables.  There are *automatic* macro variables, which you can view with

```
%put _automatic_;
```

And some other system-generated macro variables are sometimes just stored as regular global macro variables, which you can view with:

```
%put _global_;
```

or

```
%put _all_;
```

Which will print all currently defined macro variables - run it at startup and you'll see just the ones SAS defines.

What you show there are macro variables that perhaps are standard *for your company*, but don't have any standard meaning.  I would posit that `&dsin` is an input dataset to a macro, and `&dsout` is an output dataset, and the other two are year/month stamped variables, but they don't have any official, standard definition, nor would I say those are particularly commonly seen.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not generic, they are specific to your program or company but you can make educated guesses. DS is a common abbreviation for data set.

- &dsin. = Input data set
- &dsout. = Output data set
- &cj_yyyymm_1. = some date parameter, probably like 202110
- &cj_yyyymm_2. = some other date parameter....

CJ could mean something specific at your company or may reference something in your code.